# MonoGame is keeping old touches

Tags: c#, windows, touch, monogame

I'm having trouble with touches getting stuck and never going away.

I made a test program and it happens when the touch (in this case the mouse button using TouchPanel.EnableMouseTouchPoint = true) is held down then released when the cursor is out of the window. The touch point will get stuck and continue to exist. Doing this you could build up a large stack of old non-existent touches.

Relevant code:

```
TouchCollection touches;
```

then in initialize:

```
TouchPanel.EnableMouseTouchPoint = true;
```

Update:

```
touches = TouchPanel.GetState();
```

then in draw:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
for (int i = 0; i < touches.Count; i++)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(debugPoint, touches[i].Position);
}    
spriteBatch.End();
```

I've tried this with VisualStudio 2015, monogame 3.5 & 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a bug in MonoGame that I had fixed in a local branch. So, I went and created a real pull-request. You can view the fix here:

https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/pull/5518